# JavaFX - Set different hover colors on toggle button based on toggle state

Tags: css, javafx, togglebutton

I have a toggle button in my program that starts/stops a script. I would like for this button to be green and say "START" when the button is not selected, and red and say "STOP" when it is selected. More importantly, I would like the unselected hover color to be a slightly darker version of the original green, and the selected hover color to be a slightly darker version of the red color. My current CSS for this button looks like this:

```
#startStopButton {
    -fx-border-color:#d4d4d4;
    -fx-background-color:#85eca5;
    -fx-background-image: url("startButton.png");
    -fx-background-size: 50px;
    -fx-background-repeat: no-repeat;  
    -fx-background-position: 80% 50%;
    -fx-alignment: CENTER_LEFT; 
    -fx-effect: dropshadow(three-pass-box, #e7e7e7, 15, 0, 0, 0);
}

#startStopButton:hover {
    -fx-background-color:#80dc9c;
}


#startStopButton:selected{
    -fx-background-color: #ff6060;
    -fx-text:"STOP";
}
#startStopButton:selected:focused{
    -fx-background-color: #ff6060;
    -fx-text:"STOP";
}
```

Currently, this will work fine, except for when the button turns red. In this case, there is no hover effect. Within my FXML controller, there is a function that is activated every time this button is clicked:

```
private void startStopClick()
{
    if(startStopButton.isSelected())
    {
    startStopButton.setText("      STOP");
   // startStopButton.setStyle()
    }
    else {
        startStopButton.setText("     START");
    }
}
```

Is there any way to 1) set the button text within CSS so that I can leave that out of my controller?
2) Get the current toggle button state in CSS, so that I can have multiple hover effects. For example, something like this:

```
#startStopButton:unselected{
    -fx-background-color: #ff6060;
    -fx-text:"STOP";
}
```

If there is no way to do this in CSS, can I set the hover styles in the Java code in the FXML controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS properties are only available for the look of nodes. With a few exceptions the basic JavaFX nodes don't allow you to specify content via CSS. The `text` property of buttons is no exception; it cannot be set using CSS.

As for the colors: The rules occuring last override values assigned by rules with the same precedence occuring before them. This means the background color assigned by the rules for `#startStopButton:selected` and `#startStopButton:selected:focused` always override the color `#startStopButton:hover` assigns.

Since in both cases you want a darker color when hovering, the `derive` function and a lookedup color may work for you.

#### Example

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    ToggleButton btn = new ToggleButton();
    btn.getStyleClass().add("start-stop");
    btn.textProperty().bind(Bindings.when(btn.selectedProperty()).then("      STOP").otherwise("     START"));
    Pane p = new Pane(btn);

    Scene scene = new Scene(p);
    scene.getStylesheets().add("style.css");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

#### style.css

```css
.start-stop.toggle-button {
    base-color: #85eca5;
    -fx-background-color: base-color;
}

.start-stop.toggle-button:selected {
    base-color: #ff6060;
}

.start-stop.toggle-button:hover {
    -fx-background-color: derive(base-color, -20%);
}
```

---

If you cannot use `derive` since you need to specify different colors for all 4 states you could still rely on looked-up colors to avoid relying on the rule ordering:

```css
.start-stop.toggle-button {
    unselected-color: blue;
    selected-color: yellow;

    -fx-background-color: unselected-color;
}

.start-stop.toggle-button:hover {
    unselected-color: red;
    selected-color: green;
}

.start-stop.toggle-button:selected {
    -fx-background-color: selected-color;
}
```

Comment: Did not know about base-color. This is extremely helpful, thank you!

Comment: @ConnorS `base-color` is not some special name. It's just a name for a color that I chose, see [CSS Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#typecolor) (Take a look at the section below the named colors)